# C# + get all/mutiple control controls by tag name + open xml

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm using below code to get a content control by its tag-name.

```
// Gets content control of the sub table by tag.
var sdtSubTable =
    mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>()
    .Where(s => s.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag().Val.Value.Contains("tagname"));
```

But this only returns one control, however I have multiple content controls with the same name and I need to retrieve all using LINQ.

LINQ will save time hence using it otherwise would have to loop all content control and then find the matching one.

Any help on this?

Comment: LINQ also has to loop through everything. Hopefully what you meant is that it will preserve _readability_. Aside from that, you'll have to share what your XML looks like because right now, it looks like it would return multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

```
List<SdtBlock> sdtSubTable = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
    (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.Value.Contains("tagname")).ToList();
```